# Kernel and Image

Tags: linear-algebra

I have to find the kernel for this transformation:
$$T(p(x))=xp(1)-xp'(1)$$

My solution so far:
$p'(1)=0$
Hence $T(p(x))=xp(1)$

So $xp(1)=0$
Either $x=1$ or $p(1)=0$?

How do you solve the kernel from this point?
Thank you!

Comment: What is $p(x)$? A polynomial?

Comment: It is probably a good idea to specify the domain and the range of the linear transormation. Is it the vector space of polynomials of any degree, or perhaps the vector space of polynomials of degree less than 3?

Comment: T : R2[x] → R2[x]

Comment: Why would you have $p'(1)=0$? First you take the derivative, then you insert $1$, not the other way around.

Comment: My mistake, thank you. So p'(x=1)=0?

Comment: zero vector in ℝ[2]- (0,0)

Comment: A question about the solution suggested: why x can't be 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A polynomial $p(x)$ is in the kernel of $T$ iff it is mapped to the zero polynomial $q(x)=(0,0)^T$.

So, in order to be in the kernel, $(Tp)(x)=xp(1) - xp'(1)= x(p(1) - p'(1))$ needs to be equal to $q$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$. This is only possible if $p(1)=p'(1)$.

For $p(x)=ax^2 + b x + c$, which values of $a,b,c\in \mathbb R^2 $ allow this identity?

Comment: Thank you. I have a question: why x can't be 0?

Comment: p(1)=a+b+c, p'(1)=2+b. a+b+c=2+b-> a+c=2

Comment: @Ils $x$ can be zero, but we're looking for a solution where the equation is true for all $x$. Also, in your second comment: $p'(x)=2a*x + b$. Also note that $a,b,c\in \mathbb R ^2$ (If $T$ is defined on $\mathbb R ^2[x]$), so $a+c$ can't be a number.